# React-Testing Library and MSW v2 renderHook returns no data on RTKQ

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, rtk-query, msw

I have set up a test so that I can test a RTKQ to return a simple json back. I get the IsSuccess true but data us undefined. Can see it go from isLoading to is Success so the call is being observed to some degree.

```
const handlers = [
    http.post(`${BASE_URL_TOKEN}`, () =>
        HttpResponse.json({})
    ),
    http.get(`${BASE_URL}/admin/test`, () => {

        return HttpResponse.json({ data: 'Hello World' });
    }),
];

const server = setupServer(...handlers);

beforeAll(() => server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'error' }));

afterEach(() => {
    server.resetHandlers();
});

afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
});

const wrapper = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}> 
         {children}</Provider>;


test('renders hook', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useTestQuery(), {
        wrapper,
    });


    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));

    console.log('expect to see data', result.current);

    expect(result.current.data).toBeDefined();
});
```

api layer

```
export const adminApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'admin-Api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: `${BASE_URL}/admin/` }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        test: builder.query<Test, void>({
            query: () => ({
                url: 'test',
                method: httpMethod.Get,
            }),
        }),
    }),
});
```

model

```
export interface Test {
    data: string;
}
```

Tried several approaches using RTKQ and React Testing Library but cannot get data to pass. Not sure if its an issue with MSW or React Testing Library. Any advice welcome.